# Agg across columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count all `product_id` depending on following condition:

- `shared_product`==1
- `exclusive_product_storeA` ==1
- `exclusive_product_storeB` ==1

Main df

```
date         product_id  shared_product exclusive_product_storeA  exclusive_product_storeB
2019-01-01  34434        1              0                         0
2019-01-01  43546        1              0                         0
2019-01-01  53288        1              0                         0
2019-01-01  23444        0              1                         0
2019-01-01  25344        0              1                         0
2019-01-01  42344        0              0                         1
```

Output DF

```
date        count_shared_product count_exclusive_product_storeA  count_exclusive_product_storeB
2019-01-01  3                    2                               1
```

This is what I have tried - but this does not give me the desired output df:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['shared_product','exclusive_product_storeA','exclusive_product_storeB'],aggfunc=['count'],values='product_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to exclude rows that have a value of 0, groupby date and the resulting column, and finally unstack to get your final result

```
(
    df.drop("product_id", axis=1)
    .set_index("date")
    .stack()
    .loc[lambda x: x == 1]
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .sum()
    .unstack()
    .rename_axis(index=None)
)

         exclusive_product_storeA   exclusive_product_storeB    shared_product
  2019-01-01       2                      1                          3
```

A shorter path would be to exclude the product_id, groupby date and sum the columns :

```
df.drop("product_id", axis=1).groupby("date").sum().rename_axis(None)
```